# What is the systemctl equivalent

Tags: systemd, services

I am converting a package from .rpm to .deb using [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux). However, to test and debug the application I need to run it. The programs readme explains to run it as a service with:

```
systemctl enable progname.service
systemctl start progname.service
```

*What is the equivalent on ubuntu for these commands?*

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart ` is what I was looking for when I found this.

Comment: As of 2018, Ubuntu does use the newer systemd `systemctl` (as does any system above Ubuntu 15.04, Debian 8, CentOS 7, Fedora 15...). The old `/usr/sbin/service` utility calls `systemctl` if/when the system is running systemd.

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu is currently planning/developing to use *systemd* in the future. See following links for info: [Vivid will switch to booting with systemd...](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2015-March/001130.html) and [Release notes: Boot and service management](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management)

I am using 14.04.

You can use the more native command `update-rc.d`. Check the man page.

Enabling a service with defaults (see man page):

```
sudo update-rc.d foo_service defaults
```

Disabling a service:

```
sudo update-rc.d foo_service remove
```

Note that in order to remove without error message the *foo_service* file must not be present. However you can force:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f foo_service remove
```

Comment: There's no *maybe* about it. 15.04 uses systemd.

Comment: the post announcing the switch during development: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2015-March/001130.html, the release notes of the final release: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management

Answer (score 5):

systemctl is the control utility for systemd:

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

Note that Ubuntu doesn't use systemd, it uses upstart, which does a few of the same things in principle, but has some different concepts.

Without much knowledge about systemd, and based on what I read in the document I posted, I think you don't need to "enable" a service. Just dropping the .conf file for your service in /etc/init should make upstart aware of it.

That's the crux of the matter, though: the systemd config file for your service won't work unmodified on Ubuntu, you have to "translate" that to an equivalent version for Upstart. Here's documentation for upstart:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Once you have a suitable upstart .conf file, you can start a service (equivalent, I think, to systemctl start) using:

```
start your-service
```

Comment: The trouble is, starting 13.10, Ubuntu *does* use systemd's logind, which by default suspends a laptop when the lid is closed. If you want it to lock the screen before this happens, you need to hang a systemd service off the lid closure, and to do that you seem to need `systemctl`.  See http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8411 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148829 for example.

Answer (score 5):

Default package on 14.04 is `systemd-services` that doesn't provides the `systemdctl` command.

### Read

You **must read** the article [How To Install And Test Systemd On Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr And Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-and-test-systemd-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) if you want to use `systemd`.

### *Pitti* PPA

There is a PPA [`ppa:pitti/systemd`](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/systemd) that provide the adequate package for LTS 12.04, 14.04 and upcoming.