# autofs is not able to mount the remote folder

Tags: automount, init.d, etc, autofs

Hi I am trying to automount remote file system using autofs. For this I installed autofs

```
% sudo apt-get install cifs-utils autofs
```

Then I edited /etc/auto.master to have the following line:

```
/ufs   /etc/auto.ufs
```

Then I created a file /etc/auto.ufs and edited it with the following line:

```
cad -rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 fiji.csl.cornell.edu:/usr/local/cad
```

Then I restarted autofs using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/autofs restart
```

and I got following message:

```
 * Stopping automount...                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 

 * Starting automount...  
                                                                                                                         /usr/sbin/automount: program is already running.
                                                                                                                                          [ OK ]
```

But still when I try to do `ls` in the /ufs folder it does not show anything. Can somebody tell what could be the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
automount: files
```

to the file

```
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

unless, of course, it is there already.

Next, enable autofs with the command (I think):

```
# systemctl enable autofs
```

You can check enabling with

```
# systemctl is-enabled autofs
```

Comment: systemctl is not a Ubuntu utility? I don't find it installed on my machine ( ubuntu 14.04 )

Comment: My apologies: I just copied this from `autofs` docs; see http://askubuntu.com/questions/304860/what-is-the-systemctl-equivalent about this; I couldn't immediately see if it's straight-forward or involves more clunkiness.

Comment: Hey ralph, I would suggest not posting an answer if you do not know what it means